# "bootstrap compatable calendar" not starting on monday

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, date, calendar

I'm trying to get this Code working for me:

https://codepen.io/bbarry/pen/Eopdk

I want the calender to start at monday. I already changed the days:[] from Sa-So to Mo-Su in the .js.

But this changes only the header. The dates are still wrong, the 1st of december is still on a Wednesday, but it should be a Tuesday this year.

I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere in the near this part in the .html:

```
 <thead>
  <tr class="c-weeks">
    {{ for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { }}
      <th class="c-name">
        {{: days[i] }}
      </th>
    {{ } }}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {{ for (j = 0; j < 6 && (j < 1 || mode === 'month'); j++) { }}
  <tr>
    {{ for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) { }}
    {{ if (thedate > last) { dayclass = nextmonthcss; } else if (thedate >= first) { dayclass = thismonthcss; } }}
    <td class="calendar-day {{: dayclass }} {{: thedate.toDateCssClass() }} {{: date.toDateCssClass() === thedate.toDateCssClass() ? 'selected':'' }} {{: daycss[i] }} js-cal-option" data-date="{{: thedate.toISOString() }}">
      <div class="date">{{: thedate.getDate() }}</div>
      {{ thedate.setDate(thedate.getDate() + 1);}}
    </td>
    {{ } }}
  </tr>
  {{ } }}
</tbody>
```

I already tried to change the loop `(i = 0; i < 7; i++)` But I am not able to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop `for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)` in html file just print 7 header cells, iterating the array `days` and printing the array value in the cell. As you have seen, this not affects the date. You need to handle the date object.

You have 2 date objects in the html file: one used for month view, and the other used for week view and day view.

**Month view**

Date object is instantiated at line 12 of html file:

```
first = new Date(year, month, 1),
```

This means new date object, passing arguments year (above as current year) and month (defined above as current year). Third argument is the day of the month to be considered as first day of the month. Set this parameter 0.

```
first = new Date(year, month, 0),
```

**Week view**

Date object is instantiated at line 20 of html file:

```
thedate = new Date(date);
```

and date is set at line 21:

```
thedate.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay());
```

Just set date as follows:

```
thedate.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay()+1);
```

**Day view**: no changes needed, because you use the same object of week view.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Most of all thank you for the explanation, so I can understand the solution to my problem!